# How to Create Your Own Oculus Video App Channel for Gear VR?

Tags: video-streaming, channel, virtual-reality, oculus, samsung-galaxy-gear

How to Create Apps Like Vrideo and Discovery VR for Oculus Video App?

How to create channels like for VR?

Answer (score 2):

The guide to build your own VR App is

http://talesfromtherift.com/build-your-first-vr-app-for-the-oculus-rift/

And Oculus provided less info about Channels and Streaming to VR

https://developer3.oculus.com/documentation/publish/latest/concepts/publish-release-channels/